# Since field extensions are vector spaces over ground fields, how is linear algebra used to study them?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I've already taken a semester of Galois theory, so I'm not asking about anything that would be covered there, like the tower theorem. Specifically, multiplication by an element of a field extension is an invertible linear transformation over the ground field. Can anything by learned by placing the topology of a vector spce on the field extension? Are there any applications of representation theory? Representing multiplication by an element as a linear transformation, are there any useful interpretations of the determinant?

Comment: Indeed. I don't have much time right now, but a first course in Algebraic Number Theory is filled with the linear algebra of the multiplication map you mention. See for example the definitions of trace and norm of an algebraic number, and the discriminant and different of an algebraic number field. I'll add more as an answer if I have time later.

Comment: Okay, well how about we restrict to subfields of the complex numbers, and use the topology given by the Euclidean metric?

Comment: take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748503/for-which-polynomials-f-is-the-subset-fxx%E2%88%88%E2%84%A4-of-%E2%84%A4-closed-under-multipl/1748519#1748519

Comment: Also look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski's_theorem and its applications to number theory.